# How do association bonuses work

Tags: discussion

A while ago, I earned an association bonus. It was 100 reputation. Now every stackexchange site I sign up for under my email address automatically has 101 reputation. I was curious as to how these association bonuses work? How are they awarded?

Comment: The +1 is because you start with 1 rep. 1 + 100 = 101.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I know.

Comment: Ah, I see. Apologies, I misread what you were asking.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Hey, that's okay, I misread things too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work):

> you associate accounts of two or more Stack Exchange network sites,
>   and at least one of those accounts already has 200 or more reputation:
>   +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site).